# Laravel AssertJsonCount on a nested array

Tags: json, testing, laravel-5, phpunit, assert

How can I call `assertJsonCount` using an indexed, nested array?

In my test, the following JSON is returned:

```
[[{"sku":"P09250"},{"sku":"P03293"}]]
```

But attempting to use `assertJsonCount` returns the following error:

```
$response->assertJsonCount(2);

// Failed asserting that actual size 1 matches expected size 2.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may or may not be specific to Laravel. Although a Laravel helper is involved, this issue may occur elsewhere.

`assertJsonCount` utilises the PHPUnit function `PHPUnit::assertCount` which uses a laravel helper `data_get`, which has the following signature:

```
/**
 * Get an item from an array or object using "dot" notation.
 *
 * @param  mixed   $target
 * @param  string|array|int  $key
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return mixed
 */
function data_get($target, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $target;
    }
    ...
```

We can see that the JSON returned is a nested array, so logically we should pass in a key of 0.

```
$response->assertJsonCount($expectedProducts->count(), '0');
```

However this will be ignored as `assertCount` function checks if a key has been passed using `is_null`.

To overcome this, we can count all children of 0:

```
$response->assertJsonCount($expectedProducts->count(), '0.*');
```

This will produce the desired result.